# How to control a remote website within a shell script

Tags: html, bash, shell

I've a challange where I don't know how to start with

On a given website I can create a backup file with my personal settings within a few mouse clicks.
After creating the backup zip-file I'm able to download that file with my local browser and store it locally where ever I want.

I would like to  make this process automatic from a shell script so I can schedule this with the crontab of a linux box. Unfortunately I've no glue how to start with.

Any idea, any hint is welcome!

Comment: If the site provides an API, you'd start by writing code to integrate with that API.  If not, then "screen scraping" (sometimes also called "site scraping") is likely your next option, in which you'd write code to mimic your browser's HTTP requests and handle the responses.  Whether this is done directly in the bash shell or in a program of any language that's simply invoked by your shell, that's up to you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `selenium`(https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

Comment: Alternatively, if it's a zip file with a known location, it might be as easy as using `wget` or `curl` to download it from a script.